# Making 2 child elements occupy same space without parent collapsing

Tags: html, css

Well, I guess the title explains my goal, is it possible?

I want this so I can add the following CSS..

```
.bawrap:hover > .after {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear .15s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear .15s;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear .15s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear .15s;
    transition: all 1s linear .15s; }

.bawrap:hover > .before {
    opacity: 100;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear .15s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear .15s;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear .15s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear .15s;
    transition: all 1s linear .15s;
}
```

to make a before and after animated image.

Comment: What do you mean by *occupy same space*?

Comment: By occupying the same space I mean that they are on top of each other

Comment: I did it previously by just giving the parent a position relative and the children a position of absolute, but that makes the parent collapse, if i don't manually set the height and width of the parent, to that of the children.

Comment: Are the dimensions of both children the same? By the way, it would probably be better to move the transition related properties to a single rule whose selector matches both elements.

Comment: Leave one in normal flow, and position the other one absolute, in regard to the container element.

Answer (score 0):

for this you need used the property nth-child, example:

```
.bawrap:nth-child(1):hover: > .after {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear .15s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear .15s;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear .15s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear .15s;
    transition: all 1s linear .15s; }

.bawrap:nth-child(2):hover > .before {
    opacity: 100;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear .15s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear .15s;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear .15s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear .15s;
    transition: all 1s linear .15s;
}
```